# What's the difference between async io and do io in non-main thread?

Tags: asynchronous, io

I've read some articles about async IO. But I don't understand the difference between async io and do IO in non-main thread.

I mean, we can do sync IO in a new-born thread, not in the main thread, it will not block the main thread, so why we need async IO?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IO subsystem supports multiple concurrent requests. Unless you're doing completely sequential and very large reads and writes you have to use async requests to get the most out of the IO subsystem - blocking the main thread isn't the concern.